# Does ROS support proxy connections between client/server?

Tags: service, network, tcpros, topic, udpros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS Community,

Does ROS support proxy connections (like SOCKS) between client/server (to get through firewalls/VPNs)?

Thanks,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159176/does-ros-support-proxy-connections-between-client/server?/) by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2014-04-30**:
This seems like a must have for any TCP/IP connection. Does anybody else feel this way if it is not currently implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not currently support any kind of native tunneling across firewalls.

There are a few proxy nodes and bridge/aggregation nodes such as rosproxy and rosbridge that can proxy multiple topics and services from one ROS master to another, across a single TCP port; I've seen people use these to cross firewall and network boundaries.

I've also seen a number of solutions that use VPN to cross firewalls.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2014-04-30**:
Thanks Austin,

I see a need for this, and I am going to add proxy support to the Happy Artist Java based ROS Client.

Aaron